# set noautoread for one function

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

consider the bit of vimscript like:

```
func! ClangFormatFile()
    silent exec ":! mv % %.old && clang-format %.old >> %"
endfunc
```

which means I'd like to format the current file with `clang-format` but keep the old version.

On top of that I'd like to disable the "File has changed, do you want to reload?" prompt, but just reload the file.

Using `set autoread`, then execute the `mv` and `clang-format`, then `set noautoread` within the function has unfortunately no effect.

Comment: Why not just add `e! %` to line 3? Does that solve it for you?

Comment: Well, it does in a way. But then all folds are collapsed and the cursor is set to line 1, which in fact is more annoying than the load confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clang-format` reads from stdin, so you can use `%!` to filter the entire buffer to it:

```
func! ClangFormatFile()
    silent exec ":%!clang-format"
endfunc
```

Of course, you can still make a backup file if you want:

```
func! ClangFormatFile()
    silent exec ":!mv % %.old"
    silent exec ":%!clang-format"
endfunc
```

The advantage of this is that it works for any buffer, including those without a filename or with unsaved content. For example, what if someone makes modifications to a buffer, *doesn't* save, and then runs your version of `ClangFormatFile()`? Those changes would then be lost.

In general, you should always avoid modifying files directly if possible. If a tool doesn't support this, then it's probably best to make a simple wrapper script.